# assertion failure for backprojection

Tags: android, opencv

I try to make object tracking using CamShift.
But I have received error.This error became from back projection

Here is error message from LOGCAT

Assertion failed (rsz == dims*2 || (rsz == 2 && _1d) || (rsz == 0 && images.depth(0) == CV_8U)) in void cv::calcBackProject(cv::InputArrayOfArrays, const std::vector&, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, const std::vector&, double)

Here is my code. Can anybody help me?(sory my poor eng)

public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame)
{

```
     mrgba=inputFrame.rgba();

     firstTime++;

     Mat roiHist=new Mat();

     //  set up the ROI for tracking
     // implemented only one time
    if(firstTime==2)
    {
      imgRoi=mrgba.submat(roi.x,roi.x+roi.width,roi.y,roi.y+roi.height);

      Imgproc.cvtColor(imgRoi,mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);//hsv'yi bul     
      Core.inRange(mHsv,new Scalar(0,60,32), new Scalar(180,255,255), mask);
      roiHist=HistogramAndNormalize();
    }
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mrgba,mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2HSV);
    List<Mat> lHSV= Arrays.asList(mHsv);
    Mat backproj = new Mat();
    Imgproc.calcBackProject(lHSV, new MatOfInt(0, 1),roiHist, backproj,new    MatOfFloat(0, 179, 0, 255), 1);
    RotatedRect rect=Video.CamShift(backproj,roi, new TermCriteria(TermCriteria.EPS,10,1));
    roi = rect.boundingRect();
    Core.rectangle( mrgba,new org.opencv.core.Point(roi.x,roi.y),new org.opencv.core.Point(roi.x+roi.width,roi.y+roi.height),
    new Scalar(0,255,0,255));   
    return mrgba;
}
```

Comment: add code formatting, please

Comment: Now do the same to your error message; please, simply make your question as beautiful as possible.

Comment: Did you find what was wrong?